# If an MIT licensed repo relicenses to GPL3, is my derived project impacted in any way?

Tags: mit, gpl-3, relicensing

A year ago I participated in a group project to develop a small game for a class. My work involved level generation, and I later reused the code I wrote for the group project in a separate personal project. The group project used the MIT license, while my personal project does not have a license applied to it.

The title is a bit misleading, as the only derived code from the group project was what I myself wrote. I made no use of anything in the group project outside of what I wrote.

The maintainer for the group project repo has requested permission to re-license to GPL3 instead of the MIT license. If the group project was re-licensed to GPL3, would my personal project be impacted in any way?

Comment: I suppose the related question applies here too. I was uncertain if this situation applied, since I was made aware of the re-license beforehand.